# Node.JS - Filename won't accept a variable

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

doesn't work:

```
console.log(obj.html_template);    // outputs "myfile.html"
var html = fs.readFileSync(JSON.stringify(obj.html_template)); // file not found.
```

works:

```
console.log(obj.html_template);    // "myfile.html"
var html = fs.readFileSync("myfile.html"); // Works.
```

I'm going crazy.

Comment: and what does `JSON.stringify(obj.html_template)` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `JSON.stringify`, it will convert all the Strings to the JSON format Strings, with surrounding double quotes. Quoting [ECMAScript 5.1 Specification for `JSON.stringify`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.3),

> If `Type(value)` is `String`, then return the result of calling the abstract operation `Quote` with argument *value*.

And the `Quote` operation, is defined [here](http://es5.github.io/#Quote), which basically surrounds the string with `"` and takes care of special characters in the String.

So `JSON.stringify` converts, a string, for example, `abcd.txt` to `"abcd.txt"`, like this

```
console.log(JSON.stringify("abcd.txt"));
// "abcd.txt"
```

which is not equal to `abcd.txt`.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify("abcd.txt") == "abcd.txt");
// false
```

but equal to `"abcd.txt"`.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify("abcd.txt") == '"abcd.txt"');
// true
```

So, your program searches for a file named `"abcd.txt"` instead of `abcd.txt`. That is why it is not able to find the file and fails.

To fix this problem, just drop the `JSON.stringify` and pass the string directly, like this

```
var html = fs.readFileSync(obj.html_template);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
> JSON.stringify('myfile.html')
""myfile.html""
```

Your code is looking for the file `"myfile.html"` (note the superfluous quotes) in the filesystem.  It doesn't exist.

Just look for it without stringification:

```
var html = fs.readFileSync(obj.html_template);
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `JSON.stringify` in the first place? you should be able to just do

```
var html = fs.readFileSync(obj.html_template);
```